# FFMPEG.WASM in Chrome Extension Manifest Version 3: CSP, web_accessible_resources Problem

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, manifest, manifest.json

I am creating a Chrome extension,

My Content.js, which will be excuted if url is found to be: "https://erp.eloginweb.com/StudentApp/Syllabus?v=90"

```
import { createFFmpeg, fetchFile } from '@ffmpeg/ffmpeg'
async function ffmpeg() {
    console.log("This is FFMPEG speaking!!!");
    const ffmpeg = createFFmpeg({ log: true });
    await ffmpeg.load();
}
ffmpeg();
```

Now, When I open "https://erp.eloginweb.com/StudentApp/Syllabus?v=90", As expected content.js is executed but I FFMPEG fails to load with the below error:

[image: Console]

Though I did try many things to fix this but still I am noob at CSP and web_accessible_resources, Some help will be really really appreacited

I tried adding csp and web_accessible_resources as below:

```
"web_accessible_resources": [
        {
            "resources": ["node_modules/@ffmpeg/core/dist/ffmpeg-core.js", "node_modules/@ffmpeg/core/dist/ffmpeg-core.wasm", "node_modules/@ffmpeg/core/dist/ffmpeg-core.worker.js"],
            "extension_ids": ["liddjnldemgkpaadhmggbmahbhgocfee"]
        }
    ],
    "content_security_policy": {
        "extension_pages": "script-src 'self'; object-src 'self'"
    }
```

I tried many different combination but none worked, Some help will be really appreaciated

Comment: CSP `extension_pages` doesn't apply to content scripts. You can insert an extension iframe in the web page and use ffmpeg inside.

Comment: @wOxxOm How about devtools UI, does it work there? Cause for my extension I am using devtools UI too.

Comment: You can add an iframe using the same html file there as well.

Comment: @wOxxOm I have tried injecting iframe on webpage but No matter what I do, that error is not leaving me, Please help me

Answer (score 0):

I have created a simple example of getting ffmpeg to work on the options page.
I don't know if this will help you directly, but if you are interested, please see the repository below.
https://github.com/Aniny21/browser-extension-ffmpeg

The CSP settings for this are as follows:

```json
"content_security_policy": {
    "extension_pages": "script-src 'self' 'wasm-unsafe-eval'; object-src 'self';",
    "sandbox": "sandbox allow-scripts allow-forms allow-popups allow-modals; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' 'wasm-unsafe-eval'; child-src 'self';"
}
```